# Using archive-page instead of single-page improper?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I want to display all my custom post type project images on a template page, such as single-project.php, but the url doesn't display like I want it to.

It should be 'sitename/projects/' but it displays like 'sitename/projects/slug-of-post'.

Is there a way to modify the 'slug-of-post' ?

OR should I be creating an archive-projects instead to achieve that url since it does display 'sitename/project/' ? or is that wrong to use it like that?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display the images on a page through using a page template you will be able to choose the page slug as you please.

Then what you want is a page template file like this: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/#creating-custom-page-templates-for-global-use

This will have something like this in the file header:
`<?php /* Template Name: Example Template */ ?>`

Alternatively, yes, have an `archive-projects.php` to display an archive (collection of all content) of the post type.
Make sure your custom post type has an archive.

See `has_archive` in the documentation of `register_post_type()`:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/

This can also be changed for already registered post types (eg if a plugin registered the post type)

Comment: Thanks for your help, ibes. I think i need to familiarize myself with the wp hierarchy..

Comment: That is a great idea!

It is not that difficult but will help you a lot in understand what WordPress is doing under the hood.